# Is b*a(a+b)* equivalent to (a+b)*a(a+b)*?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

So two regular expressions are equivalent if they are associated, i.e., produce the same regular language, I am curious about this because it is clear that the language produced by $b*a(a+b)*$ is contained in $(a+b)*a(a+b)*$, but something tells me at least a string of characters would be left out if we only consider $b*a(a+b)*$, can you provide at least a string of characters in $(a+b)*a(a+b)*$ but not in $b*a(a+b)*$?

Comment: "*But something tells me at least a string of characters would be left out*"  What tells you this?

Comment: A hunch, nothing really, just the idea that I'm wrong.

Comment: Suppose you have some string of a's and b's from the language generated by `(a+b)*a(a+b)*`... So, we will have some sequence (*possibly empty*) of a's and/or b's in a "first block", then an "a", then again some sequence of a's and/or b's in a "last block".  Let us reimagine such a string by finding the first "a" that occurs.  Call what (*if anything*) comes before it as the "first block" and everything that follows the "last block".  It is clear that since that was the first "a" that everything that came before it must have exclusively been "b"s...

Comment: @JMoravitz, so they would generate the same language if you see it like that, strings containing at least one a?

Comment: Yes, both regular expressions can be thought of as "strings of a's and/or b's such that they contain at least one a."

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you, that settles it.

Comment: The first one can match on some strings that starts with `b`, like `ba`. But if the second one matches on something with a `b` at all, that `b` was preceded by an `a`. The second one cannot match strings that start with `b`.

Comment: @2'59'2 I didn't quite follow your comment, (a+b)*a(a+b)* can match strings starting with b because (a+b)* is the Kleene's closure of (a+b), taking all the possible combinations of a and b, including b itself.

Comment: @2'59'2 The notation used by the OP seems clear from context to read that the first parentheses allows for either an `a` or a `b`, and this parenthesis occurs any number of times zero or more and what occurs each time does not need to be the same.  In other words, any string made of a's and/or b's including the empty string.  This is then followed by an `a`, and then followed by again any string consisting of `a`'s and/or `b`'s, possibly empty.  Perhaps you are confusing it with a specific programming language's implementation of regex

Comment: Yeah if `+` means "or" then forget what I wrote. I am assuming `+` means "1 or more". I've never seen it mean something else, but I get it now that it could mean what `|` often means.